# Printing Input to Output File

Tags: python

Trying to write a program that prompts the user for the name of an output file, then copies the rest of the lines into the output file until the user enters a period as the first character on a line.

This is what I have so far. I've got it to work so that it asks for the input and stops once the user enters "." as the first character on a line. However, I'm sure I'm doing this totally wrong because my output is really weird. I'm a beginner so I'm not familiar with more complex functions. So the most basic and simple way to do this would be of great help.

```
output_file=input("Enter Output File")
outfile = open(output_file,"w")
text=input("")  
for line in text:
    if text[0] == ".":
        break
    text=input('') 
    print(line, file=outfile)
outfile.close()
```

Input

```
hello world
.
```

Output:

```
h
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for` iterates over an iterable (like a list or a string). You want to repeat code until some condition is not met anymore. To do that, use a while loop:

```
text = ''
while text != '.':
    print(text, file=outfile)
    text = input('')
```

This might insert a blank line as first line in the output file (because the first time text with the value of `''` gets written). An easy workaround would be:

```
text = ''
while text != '.':
    if text != '':
        print(text, file=outfile)
    text = input('')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing `print(line, file=outfile)` and line takes the value of each character in `text`. Change the line to this :

`print(text, file=outfile)`

***Edit***

There's a better way to do this :

```
text=input("")
while text[0]!=".":
  print(text,file=outfile)
  text=input("")
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the line which reads

```
for line in text:
```

The variable `text` contains a string, and the above line will iterate through it one character at a time.

So, if you enter "hello" to the first prompt, the loop will then cycle through five times with `line` containing `h`, `e`, `l`, `l`, and `o` in that order. It might even go through once more for the newline.

Instead, you want to do something like:

```
while True:
    text = input("")
    if text[0] == ".": break
    print(text, file=outfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over `text`, which is a one-line input string, rather than over the file handle to get successive lines. Try:

```
for text in sys.stdin:
    if text[0] == '.':
        break
    outfile.write(text)
```